# How to open a new window in a webpage using javascripts when pop up is blocked

Tags: popup, window.open

I am working on a web application, where in one of the page, three external links needs to be opened one after another in an interval of 30 seconds. I have used java-scripts functions 'window.setTimeout' and 'window.open' for my requirement. It works but only if the pop up blocker option in the browser is set to false. If the pop up blocker is enabled, only the first window is opened, but the other windows are blocked by the browser. The first window is opening because the first window is associated with a direct click event but, rest of the window openings are not associated with a trusted event. Following is a snippet of the code.

```
<button onclick="openLink()" class="btnStyle">Install</button>

<script>
   function openLink() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
          window.open("someUrl, "_blank");}, 30000);
   }
</script>
```

Can anyone guide me how to overcome this problem. I have read somewhere that using ajax calls this can be done, but not sure about how to do this. I would appreciate any help.

```
Thanks in advance. 
Chandan
```

Comment: _“three external links needs to be opened one after another in an interval of 30 seconds”_ – _why?_ Where does this requirement come from? If it is a requirement in a controlled environment (such as a company network f.e.), then see to it that an exception is added to the popup blocker configuration. […]

Comment: […] If it is not such an environment – then the users where it does not work obviously _do not want_ such popups, otherwise they would have configured their blocker otherwise. Then all you can/should do is advise them to the fact that this is “necessary” – and let _them_ decide, whether or not they want to add an exception to their popup blocker for your application or not.

Comment: Hi, The requirement is that, there will be a list of applications that needs to be installed from a mobile device (from google play-store) one after another when the install button is clicked. So, whenever the install button is clicked, the user will be redirected to play-store app one after another. But, there is no way from a web page, this can be known that whether the previous app has been installed so that the next can be started. Hence, a delay of 30 seconds has come into picture.

Comment: Sounds like a trainwreck of a concept already.